# Minimum bids in first-price auction

Tags: game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium, auction-theory

Suppose there are two bidders $i=1,2$ who may either have a low valuation $V_L$ or a high valuation $V_H.$ Bidders do not know others' valuations. In a first-price auction, where ties are broken by coin-flip, what is the the minimum bids (i.e. the lowest bid in the support $\underline{b_i}$ in $[\underline{b_i},\overline{b_i}]$ for $i=1,2$) for the $V_L$ type bidder?

---

In these auctions, strategies are some probability over the domain $[\underline{b_i},\overline{b_i}]$ (i.e. a mixed strategy). My guess is that the support for both the $V_L$ type player is $0$, i.e. that $$[\underline{b_i},\overline{b_i}]=(0,V_L].$$ Furthermore, the probability of bidding close to $0$ is quite trivial, since the bidder's chance of winning is also close to $0$. However, my lecturer argues that the support $\underline{b_i}=V_L$ for both players, but this would not make bidding worthwhile for the $V_L$ type, since she would receive $0$ surplus.

Comment: What is the distribution of types?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, they're both possible with some nonzero probability. 
I believe no particular distribution is necessary for this.

Comment: In that case, bidding every type $V_L$ is certainly not a Bayes-Nash equilibrium

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't claim that. I'm only interested in the minimum bid in both players' supports.

Comment: And you believe $b_i=0$ for every type? Your lecture do not provide an actual argument for the statement given there?

Comment: $V_L$ is some positive valuation.

Comment: "The support...are...0." makes sense neither grammatically nor mathematically.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker makes sense to me (perhaps you may also say "the supports are", but there's little grammatically wrong with it). If it's mathematically wrong, please demonstrate it in an answer.

Comment: A support is a set, not a point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71293/discussion-between-pafnuti-and-michael-greinecker).

Comment: This question is cross-posted at [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19998/pure-or-mixed-strategy-in-first-price-auction).

Answer (score 0):

Did you learn game theory? with a mixed strategy, all strategy must yield the same expected unity. If the strategy of lower type is over $[0,v_l]$, no one will bid $v_l$ since bidding $v_l$ will give 0, but bidding lower than $v_l$ gives more than 0 in expectation. In this way, you can show that any interval $[0,x < v_l] $cannot be the support. Only a single point can be a support. now any singel point less than $v_l$ cannot be a support. so $v_l$ is the only support.